# Find bankbalance with Dataset

Tags: c#, wpf, database, linq, object

As a side project I am developing a basic banking system using C# and WPF to create the forms.

At the moment, I have four forms and two different global classes.

The forms are:

- Welcome Page; This form is used to create an initial dataset stored in BankData.cs. All of my database table is stored here - the table is called UserData.
- Validate User; This form is where the user enters their account number and pin. I do some validation here to ensure it's 6 characters and only integers etc. I then call the Global.cs class which has a method to option the DB and log the user in (Check if it matches). If it does, then I store the AccountNumber and PIN in the BankData.cs class.
- Options Form; This form is simply just three buttons, at the moment going to the Display Balance form.
- Display Balance; This form should display the current Balance and the Remainign Withdrawal limit for that user (£250 pounds, although this goes down when they withdraw more. They can't withdraw more than this).

My problem is when I am trying to display the Current Balance. I try to query the dataset using linq by converting it to a datatable. However, when I try to display the balance I am getting this instead of a balance:

> System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator'2[System.Data.DataRow,System.String]

I am converting everything to a string and it doesn't change this message. I also tried returning the integer value of the balance but this causes compilier errors.

I've attached the codethat should show the balance on the label from the Options Form class, and the code that finds the balance in BankData.cs

BankData.cs

```
public static string FindBalance()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = ds.Tables[0];

    var id = (from DataRow dr in dt.Rows
              where (string)dr["AccountNo"] == accountNumber
              select dr.Table.Rows[5].ToString());

    //return dt.Rows[rowNum][columName].ToString();

    return id.ToString();
}
```

DisplayBalance cs:

```
lblcurBal.Content = "Current Balance: " + BankData.FindBalance();
//Find the Balance of the Account Number here.
```

Please help.

Comment: " I try to query the dataset using linq by converting it to a datatable. " Why? you can directly access the datatables datasetname.Tables[0] or using  datasetname.Tables overloads;

Comment: This was causing me problems and when googling it said converting it to a datatable which from memory is a subset of dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working based off of the solution by vedbhawsar.

By changing the code on the BankData.cs class to:

```
var id = (from DataRow dr in dt.Rows
          where Convert.ToString(dr["AccountNo"]) == accountNumber
          select dr["Balance"]).FirstOrDefault();

return id.ToString();
```

It allows my to display the balance of the user who has logged in.

Thanks a lot; now I just need to replicate this to take the Minimum Remaining Balance. *Expect me back when it doesn't work lol.*

Thanks again everyone who helped me come to this conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

Try This: a small change in your code

```
public static string FindBalance()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = ds.Tables[0];

    var id = (from DataRow dr in dt.Rows
          where dr["AccountNo"] == accountNumber
          select dr["BalanceColumnName"]).FirstOrDefault();



    return id.ToString();
}
```

**EDIT:**

This is what worked for Paul as he described in comments below :

```
public static string FindBalance()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = ds.Tables[0];

    var id = (from DataRow dr in dt.Rows
          where Convert.ToString(dr["AccountNo"]) == accountNumber
          select dr["BalanceColumnName"]).FirstOrDefault();



    return id.ToString();
}
```

Comment: This answer also provides error detailed in comment above.

Comment: This solution worked when I changed dr["AccountNo"] to Convert.ToString(dr["AccountNo"]). Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Paul Okey, so your accountNumber Variable is in string and the datatype of the AccountNo column in database is different?

Comment: Yes, in the database my AccountNo is stored as an integer. I have no idea why it's stored as a string in the application. However, as this is a prototype as long as it works it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `id.FirstOrDefault();` in this particular case instead of `id.ToString();` as return value since `FirstOrDefault` actualy gets data from your linq query and `ToString` is just query internal string representation.

In other words, value of variable `id` is not a result of query you've wrote, it is query itself. And `FirstOrDefault` retrieves first result form this query.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer in such a short time-space. When changing the return to id.FirstOrDefault() I get this error in the output dialog: "A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in EDCP2.exe" and then it displays blank on the display balance form. As a side note, this does not crash my program it just doesn't display the balance.

Comment: @Paul Well, it probably being thrown by `(string)dr["AccountNo"]`. Until you've retrieved query result this cast haven't been actually made - that's why you haven't received this exception before. Try to examine your data table and find if it has value that can't be cast to string in `AccountNo` column.

Comment: All of the data in the Balance column are integers this is why I thought I should originally return an int. However, this threw errors and when I converted to string it didn't minus the fact it doesn't display.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `id` is an enumeration which is a collection of values, looks like you are expecting single value.

Assuming ***6th*** column of your `DataTable` represents balance,

```
public static string FindBalance()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = ds.Tables[0];

    var id = (from DataRow dr in dt.Rows
              where (string)dr["AccountNo"] == accountNumber
              select dr[5].ToString()).FirstOrDefault();

    //return dt.Rows[rowNum][columName].ToString();

    return id== null? "" : id;
}
```

Comment: Hi, this answer also provides me with the error specified in comment above.

Comment: Hi, the error is: "A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in EDCP2.exe" It doesn't cause the program to crash. It only stops the balance displaying.

Comment: @RahulSingh Sorry, your method causes the same error.

Comment: It would be helpful if you share DataTable schema/definiton.

Answer (score 0):

You need to obtain the result from the collection, using something like `FirstOrDefault()`

```
return Convert.ToString(id.FirstOrDefault());
```

You are actually calling `ToString` on the iterator, and not actually obtaining the result.

Comment: This answer also provides me with error in comment above.